# Xamarin getPlacePhotos not working

Tags: android, xamarin, google-places-api

I'm trying to get place photos using Google Place Api for Android,
but it is blocked when runs getPlacePhotos, does anyone has same issue?

My code shown as the following:

```
    public void getPlacePhotos(string placeId)
    {
        GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .AddApi(PlacesClass.GEO_DATA_API)
            .EnableAutoManage(this, 0, (cr) => {
                var x = cr.ErrorCode;
            })
            //.AddApi(Android.Gms.Location.LocationServices.API)
            .Build();
        var r = PlacesClass.GeoDataApi.GetPlacePhotosAsync(googleApiClient, placeId);
        r.Wait();  **<< Here is blocked**
        var result = r.Result;

        if (result != null)
        {
            if (result.Status.IsSuccess)
            {
                PlacePhotoMetadataBuffer photoMetadataBuffer = result.PhotoMetadata;
                var photo = (IPlacePhotoMetadata)photoMetadataBuffer.Get(0);
                //Bitmap image = photo.GetPhoto(googleApiClient).Await().GetBitmap();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use async/await properly. C# documentation can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx). Please refer to the `Wait` documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635(v=vs.110).aspx), take a look at the Remarks section.

> Wait is a synchronization method that causes the calling thread to wait until the current task has completed. If the current task has not started execution, the Wait method attempts to remove the task from the scheduler and execute it inline on the current thread. **If it is unable to do that, or if the current task has already started execution, it blocks the calling thread until the task completes**.

This is how you would do it with async/await:

```
public async Task getPlacePhotos(string placeId)
{
    ...
    var result = await PlacesClass.GeoDataApi.GetPlacePhotosAsync(googleApiClient, placeId);

    if (result != null)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And as a bonus: remember that only event handlers are allowed to not have a `Task` as a return type when doing async work. I guess your call here is not an event handler, so use of `Task` is required.

If you don't want to make the method itself async and still return void, you can wrap the content of the `getPlacePhotos` method with this:

```
Task.Run(async () => {
    // perform async work here
});
```

Comment: Thank you for The "Task.Run" trick. let me try it later, I will update the progress when I finished the job.

Comment: Same issue, no response even I ran getPlacePhotos inside the Task.Run block. Any suggestions?

Comment: The "blocked" is not just wait for a little time, it means no response forever, any suggestions for this issue?

Comment: Did you try async/await and remove the Wait method? Just using the code you already have in the Task.Run lambda isn't enough.

Comment: Finally, as you mentioned, it does work!
I run it in Task.Run without lambda, it works!
Much thanks.!